# using LINQ to delete specific rows from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I want to delete a particular row from a DataTable named dt.

For a table in SQL, I could do something like:

```
DELETE FROM dt 
WHERE BASELINE_FOLDER = baselineSubfolder
AND BASELINE_FILE = baselineFilename
AND BASELINE_CHECKSUM = baselineChecksum;
```

Is there an equivalent LINQ statement for this?

Comment: Are you using [Linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) or something similar?

Comment: tbh I don't know, so probably not. I'm brand new to LINQ and have never really used it before aside from a couple of copy-and-paste solutions I found online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have the model's and only a `DataTable` (this is what I understand from the OP).

```
//Cast to enumerable of `DataRow` and filter on your condition
var rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => row["BASELINE_FOLDER"] == baselineSubFolder && row["BASELINE_FILE" == baselineFilename
&& row["BASELINE_CHECKSUM"] == baselineChecksum).ToArray();
//Loop through and remove the rows that meet the condition
foreach(DataRow dr in rows)
{
  dt.Rows.Remove(dr);
}
```

Comment: This is giving me an error on the cast:  'System.Linq.Queryable.Cast<TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context\

Comment: @user1985189 I missed the `()` at first off of `Cast`, I have changed this now. You may need to check what references you have.

Comment: Ok thanks it compiles now. But doesn't removing a row in a foreach loop screw up the counter (because you're deleting a row during the looping process so it no longer knows how many items to loop through?) When I run it now it gives this error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.

Comment: @user1985189 your correct, please call `ToArray()` on the LINQ query :)

Comment: ok this works, but there's one more thing I didn't mention in my original question. Another condition is that another column (STATUS) must be blank/empty. However, when I add in the line `&& row["STATUS"] == ""` it doesn't execute the `dt.Rows.Remove(dr);` line. Same thing if i use `null` instead of `""`

Comment: @user1985189 Try `string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["STATUS"])` or `row["STATUS"] == DBNull.Value`.

Comment: for some reason it's disregarding both of those statements too and still removing the wrong rows... but I checked the contents of my datatable at runtime and those rows that I want to be removed are definitely in there... I can show u a picture if u want?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the data table to list and can use `RemoveAt()` to do so.

You can convert it to list and use the below code

```
string baseLineFolder=dt.Rows["BASELINE_FOLDER"].ToString();
                string baseLineFile=dt.Rows["BASELINE_FILE"].ToString();
                string baseLineChecksum=dt.Rows["BASELINE_CHECKSUM"].ToString();
                var dtresult = dt.AsEnumerable();
                var result=(from r in dtresult
                            where(r.Field<string>("BASELINE_FOLDER")!=baseLineFolder)
                            &&(r.Field<string>("BASELINE_FILE")!=baseLineFile)
                            &&(r.Field<string>("BASELINE_CHECKSUM ")!=baseLineChecksum)
                              select r).ToList();
```